# Overridden method call in parent method

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

Considering the following:

```
public class Child extends Parent{
  public boolean isMeh(){
    return true;
  }

  public void childMethod() {
    System.out.println("child: "+isMeh());
  }

  public static void main(String... args){
    Child child = new Child();
    child.parentMethod();
    child.childMethod();

  }

}

class Parent{
  public boolean isMeh(){
    return false;
  }

  public void parentMethod() {
    System.out.println("parent: "+isMeh());
  }
}
```

Output:

```
parent: true
child: true
```

It is pretty obvious when isMeh() is called within Child class, it calls the overridden method.

But when the overriden method is called within a method of the **parent** object, it still calls the child object's method.

I see that we create one child object and parentMethod is just inherited so when we call isMeh() it calls the available(overridden) one.

What would be the reason for this implementation in java?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Whenever you call something as a Child, the overridden method is called. However, if you say Parent p = new Parent(); p.isMeh(); it will just return false.

Comment: the simple thing to understand is methods are called on object and variables on reference so whenever i do parent p =new parent(), the parent method will be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any class in an inheritance hierarchy of `Parent`, be it a `Child`, a `Parent`, or some `Grandchild` deriving from them, has exactly one implementation of the method called `isMeh`. When `Child` overrides `isMeh` of `Parent` with its own implementation, it replaces the implementation; as far as the `Child` is concerned, the implementation in the `Parent` no longer applies<sup>*</sup>.

When you instantiate `Child` and call its `parentMethod`, the method has access to only one method `isMeh` - that is, the implementation provided by the `Child`. That is why you get the behavior that you describe.

This behavior allows for very nice patterns: for example, you can write a "partial implementation" of a method in the parent by relying on "plug-in" functionality in the child class provided through overrides. This technique is known as [*Template Method Design Pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

<sup>*</sup> although `Child` retains an ability to call `Parent`'s `isMeh` explicitly.